# Is ATI working on Unity 3D?

Tags: 11.04, unity, ati

Before I had ATI running, but Unity was corrupt and laggy. Now, I don't have installed and everything is better. I am just wondering if it is safe to turn it back on?

Comment: You should at least tell us which ATI graphics cards you're using. Also by saying that you have ATI running do you mean ATI propriety drivers (fglrx)?

Comment: yes it runs ok, and who knows.. it depends on your hardware

Answer (score 1):

I can also vouch for that as I always used to NOT use the proprietry driver but Unity was really glitchy with it so reinstalled ATIs FGRLX and I must admit it worked a treat

I would give it another try

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

It should then correctly reconfigure your X config as well

If you are unsure check here for a good guide to installing fglrx

[ATI How to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI)

However if it does not look any better I would check out the guide to removing it again as it is not straight forward unless you follow this guide

[getting rid of it again!](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem%3a%20%20Need%20to%20fully%20remove%20-fglrx%20and%20reinstall%20-ati%20from%20scratch)

Answer (score 0):

I have an ATI card and Unity 3D works fine.

My graphics card is ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400, it might be different with yours. Which graphics card do you have?

The default driver had a few minor glitches unfortunately. The proprietary driver works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which graphics card you have but, on the `ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470/1 GB DDR3` and `fglrx` enabled, Unity 3D works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

With my Radeon HD5850, I had very poor performance on Unity with the proprietary drivers. However, using the new and open radeon drivers, it's lightning fast. I get a few white ... spots on the dash from time to time. They're not too annoying, and except for that, everything is perfect.

In other words; if you have similar card (A HD5xxx) I would strongly suggest that you *do NOT* install the proprietary drivers. After AMD hired people to work on the open drivers full time, they've developed rapidly. In 11.10 I don't have any issues at all.